# Python, do arithmetic on list of floats extracted from sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Im trying to extract some floats from sqlite into a list, then do some calculations on that list:

```
import itertools

conn = sqlite3.connect("Rain.db")
c = conn.cursor()
conn.text_factory = float
nn_mag = c.execute('select NeuralMagnitude from NNDATA').fetchall()
conn.close()

nn_mag = list(itertools.chain(*nn_mag))[:-1]
```

the reason for `[:-1]` is otherwise the last item in the tuples/list is `None`

conn.text_factory = float does make the tuples extract as floats, but even though `nn_mag` is converted to a list of floats, its still impossible to do any arithmetic with `nn_mag`, for example code and error:

```
totals = sum(nn_mag)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

another way I have seen on Stack Overflow to sum floats in a list:

```
totals = sum(map(float,nn_mag))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks to me there are `NULL`s in your databas. Are you sure all the data are real floats?

Comment: Im loading to the database from a .csv, which is generated by another program, there are a lot of rows but as far as I know they are all populated with numbers in an x.x format

Comment: Ok the last line does have some blanks, thats the reason then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter out your problematic `None`. If you do it manually:

```
total = 0
for nn in nn_mag:
    try: total += nn
    except TypeError: pass
```

Or if it really is just `None` cells, you can use filter:

```
totals = sum(filter(lambda x: x is not None,nn_msg))
```

Comment: thanks the second one worked just fine, it appears the last row (1570) in the .csv has a differnt format and I didnt see it